# how to create a data visualization with a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, visualization

I am trying to study some codes inside a wireless communication textbook, which I have a piece of code from the textbook:

```
function PL=PL_free(fc,dist,Gt,Gr)
% Free Space Path loss Model
% Input
%       fc        : carrier frequency[Hz]
%       dist      : between base station and mobile station[m]
%       Gt        : transmitter gain
%       Gr        : receiver gain
% output
%       PL        : path loss[dB]
lamda = 3e8/fc;
tmp = lamda./(4*pi*dist);
if nargin>2
    tmp = tmp*sqrt(Gt); 
end
if nargin>3
    tmp = tmp*sqrt(Gr);  
end
PL = -20*log10(tmp);
```

And inside the textbook, there is also a graph that is generated based on this Matlab code. My question is, how can I create this graph based on the function myself? Do I need to have a data source for all of the variables? If I cannot get a data source like an excel file, is there any way inside Matlab there is a built-in tool that supports creating this graph? The graph is like this:
(I understand the concept of the plot which is in the command, enter some data of the function, but it will only show the answer of the function output. I cannot find a suitable solution anywhere online so here I come)

[image: free PL picture]

After revision:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't testet this, but something along the lines of:

```
fc = __   % Choose value
Gt = __   % Choose value
Gr = __   % Choose value

dist = logspace(0, 3, 16);
PL=PL_free(fc,dist,Gt,Gr);

semilogx(dist, PL, 'ro')
```

Alternatively:

```
dist = logspace(0, 3, 16);
PL = zeros(1, numel(dist));
for ii = 1:numel(dist)
   PL(ii) = PL_free(fc, dist, Gt, Gr);
end

semilogx(dist, PL, 'ro')
```

I'm not sure if `linspace` or `logspace` is best here.`linspace` creates a vector with equally spaced values, while `logspace` creates a vector with logarithmically spaced values. To plot more values you can do [`hold on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) or `hold all`, and do [`semilogx`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html) with a new `PL`.

Comment: I added your code onto my code and I have attached the screenshot on the question. And for 
fc = __ do I enter my own number into it?

Comment: Put my code _outside_ your code. I.e. don't edit your code, and do what I wrote in a script or directly as commands.